# Nested flexbox not working as expected in Safari Desktop

Tags: css, flexbox

This is what I expect (tested in Chrome and Firefox):

[image]
This is how it looks in Safari Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9)

[image]

Quick jsfiddle to show you an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/qbozL26m/1/

CSS:

```
.container {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.equal-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.equal-height > [class^="col-"],
.equal-height > [class*=" col-"] {
  display: flex;
  //align-items: center;
  //
  .well {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Gif och Chrome-behaviour (correct)
[image]

Gif of Safari behaviour (incorrect)

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I've come up with a solution to fix it for safari, it's not that good though because it overrides bootstraps column sizes.

```
.equal-height > [class^="col-"],
.equal-height > [class*=" col-"] {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 33%;
}
```

Comment: It looks fine in safari also for me.

Comment: @ketan I've added gifs to show the incorrect behaviour that Safari does

Comment: I am using 5.1.7 version and it look fine for me. http://i.stack.imgur.com/quGkj.png

Comment: @ketan that doesn't look fine at all, the wells/boxes should be equal height

Comment: Not working with Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9) (like OP described it).

Comment: Does it change anything, if you specify `flex` for the flex items explicitly (with the values you want for grow/shrink/basis)?

Comment: @CBroe It works when using flex-basis, but then the bootstrap classes are lost, not the end of the world but would be neat to not have to specify flex-basis (see my second edit)

Comment: What do you mean by “the bootstrap classes are lost”? They are still there, and they specify a similar width (in this case, `33.33333333%` for `col-md-4`). // You _are_ appending to what the framework offers built-in here – so  don’t see where the harm is in specifying `flex-basis` additionally, if that’s what TheNewInternetExplorer (a.k.a. Safari) needs …

Comment: @CBroe I guess i phrased it wrong. The bootstrap classes are overridden when using flex-basis.